# Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock! Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord. Is this something to worry about?

Tags: android, android-activity, timeout, android-asynctask

In my application I use `AsyncTask` in `oncreate`. Sometimes I get "Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock! Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord" in the logs. Can this cause any issue, or we can just ignore this ?

Comment: How can we be expected to help you without seeing any error logs or code? We can't simply divine what is wrong with your code

Comment: My question is: is this ok to get this in the logs... I mean is it something that can be ignored? 
The logs say - 
03-16 15:17:24.233 W/ActivityManager( 1628): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock! 
03-16 15:17:24.273 W/ActivityManager( 1628): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{40632cf8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally Found the answer.
This can be ignored.

This means that your main thread is continually running, pumping message through its message queue without ever going idle.  If that is what you want, there is nothing to fix.  This is why the log message is a warning, not an error.

Source : [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/TfkPlN5b-ig)

Comment: Nopes, it's not just warning but in case you are running this application in lower device it may cause to struggle with your device and unfortunately restart device subsequently.